# PHP JSON Object parsing

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON object in PHP. My efforts have lead to ending up with this var_dump:

```
string(5) "Malta"
string(2) "mt"
string(11) "St Julian's"
string(5) "Malta"
string(2) "mt"
string(11) "St Julian's"
```

Now what I want is just to print "Malta". All efforts of trying have failed and I need a hint into what to do next. Any ideas of how i can go about this? Thanks

Trying to parse this part: "location":

```
{
"totalFound":2,
"content":[
{
"id":"a1d17bwqeqewqeqweaf-1e54-4861-92e1-8246baba11d6",
"title":"Developer",
"refNumber":"REFqweqwe4N",
"createdOn":"2015-08-28T11:10:07.000Z",
"updatedOn":"2015-08-28T13:19:59.000Z",
"location":{
"country":"Malta",
"countryCode":"mt",
"city":"St Julian's"
},
"status":"SOURCING",
"actions":{
"details":{
"url":"www.google.com",
"method":"GET"
}
}
}
],
"offset":0,
"limit":10
}
```

My code snippet:

```
$jfo = json_decode($data, TRUE);

foreach ($jfo['content'] as $category) {
if (isset($category['title']) != null) {
}
if (isset($category['location']) != null) {



    foreach ($category['location'] as $location){
        var_dump($location);
        print_r($location);
```

Comment: can i get the print_r of that object ?

Comment: Looks more like the `var_dump` is inside a loop rather than of the decoded object?

Comment: @jon  yes i think so too

Comment: Result of print_r:   string(5) "Malta"
Maltastring(2) "mt"
mtstring(11) "St Julian's"
St Julian'sstring(5) "Malta"
Maltastring(2) "mt"
mtstring(11) "St Julian's"
St Julian's

Comment: your json isn't right according to jsonlint

Comment: @BuddhiAbeyratne fixed.

Comment: @progdoc answered on an assumption check it out

Comment: @BuddhiAbeyratne replied, its only printing first character of these three: Malta, mt, St julians

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to echo `$category['location']['country']` 
remove the for each on there 
its tying to loop your location array

Comment: tried, didn't work - its only printing the first character

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're iterating over each element in `location`, i.e. `country`, `countryCode`, and `city`.

This does what you need:

```
$jfo = json_decode($data, TRUE);

foreach ($jfo['content'] as $content)
{
  echo $content['location']['country'];
}
```